# Laravel/Apple : cors origin stricted

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-socialite, samesite

I'm having a problem
[image]

When I'm redirecting from socialite apple login it shows the photo above.
It's a cross origin problem but how to solve it?

I had to put this in session.php because I get this warning :
`Cookie “session” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite`

[image]

Comment: which laravel version?

Comment: @bhucho laravel 8

Comment: The without using package way of doing it is to define some Origin headers in your middleware and appservice Provider to deal with Origin request to solve it, but as you are using laravel 8 it comes by default with fruitcake.cors([see in your composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/composer.json#L9)) , use this package should have a cors.php as well

Comment: Also never allow `origin header as '*'` will lead to serious security issues

Comment: read this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#examples_of_access_control_scenarios) to understand how cors works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed fruitcake/laravel-cors and it got fixed.
I didn't have it because of upgrading from 5.8 to an old project.